# Titanium Backup resets my desktop background image when creating a backup

Tags: titanium-backup

I recently switch from Helium backup to Titanium (still free version) and experience a strange effect:

Each time I run a batch backup of my app data, the background image of my device is reset to the default.

Any idea why? Actually, I'm quite surprised that something is changed during backup.
And what I could do to make Titanium leave the image I selected?

I run CyanogenMod 11 / Android 4.4.4

(BTW: Is there a support forum for titanium somewhere?)

Comment: That sounds very strange, I'd ping Joël (the dev) for that. AFAIR he [offers support via his TitaniumTrack website](http://www.titaniumtrack.com/support.html). // I'm a long-time user of the Pro version (was one of the first apps I've bought, about 5 years ago), and I've never experienced such – though I must admit that lately I never changed the background image away from the default, so I wouldn't have noticed ;)